# Mongoose distinct returns empty array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have the following schema and query. I'm trying to retrieve all tags in my document by using the .distinct() method but that's not working. Any suggestions would be great.

```
const postingSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 time: String, 
 date: String, 
 company: String, 
 position: String, 
 description: String, 
 tags: Array, 
});

router.get('/tags', async function(req, res){
 const tags = await Postings.find({}).distinct("tags").exec();

 if(!tags){
     return res.status(404).json({message: "No Tags!"});
 }

 return res.status(200).json(tags);
}
```

Comment: please add more information, because your code and schema looks right, `await Postings.find({}).distinct("tags").exec()` put in a `try catch` and log the error

Comment: instead of `await Postings.find({}).distinct("tags").exec()` run this `await Postings.distinct("tags")`